# Issue returning unique words in lower case in a function:/

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to get all unique 3 character words from a sentence in lowercase but I am not sure why its not working.

sentence = "In the not too extreme cold we may find a bear"
words_list = get_unique_3_letter_words(sentence)
print(words_list)
['may', 'not', 'the', 'too']

```
def get_unique_3_letter_words(text):
    result = []
    for x in text.split():
        if len(x)==3 and (x not in result):
            result.append(x)
    result.sort()
    return result.lower()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a set to select unique elements:

```
def get_unique_3_letter_words(text):
    """returns a sorted list of unique 3 letter words from text, 
    converted to lower case.
    """
    result = set()
    for x in text.split():
        if len(x) == 3:
            result.add(x.lower())
    return sorted(list(result))
```

Comment: would this return it as lowercase though?

Comment: Yes it does, the `words` are converted to `lower case` upon being added to the `set`

Answer (score 0):

In your original code it looks like it should work except for the last line. You can't call `lower` on a list.

Change

```
result.append(x)
```

To

```
result.append(x.lower())
```

And change

```
return result.lower()
```

To

```
return result
```

That being said, this is not an efficient solution. The code has to search the entire solution set for each word. The most pythonic solution is to use a set comprehension

```
def get_unique_3_letter_words(text):
  return sorted({x.lower() for x in text.split() if len(x) == 3})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the technique you had except that you compare lower case word with itself like so:

```
def get_unique_3_letter_words(text):

    result = []

    split_text = text.split()
    for word in split_text:
        if len(word) == 3 and word.lower() == word and word not in result:
            result.append(word)

    result.sort()
    return result

sentence = "In the the not too too may extreme cold we may find a bear"
words_list = get_unique_3_letter_words(sentence)
print(words_list)
```

**Result**

```
['may', 'not', 'the', 'too']
```

Comment: Thanks but this returns 'the' twice? how can that be corrected so 3 letter words are only returned once?

Comment: I added a fix with `and word not in result:`. That fixes the issue you mentioned.